# How to Know When Curl Fails With Curl Formats

Tags: bash, curl

I am running curl from a script using curl format. The problem is that even when it fails I have time total in the output.

I really need to know if it fails.
EDIT: Fails is when it does not downloading the file (as an example the file is missing on the server).

This is the line from the script:

```
curl -f -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s  "$IP_PORT/$FILE_NAME"
```

Here is the curl format:

```
time_namelookup:        %{time_namelookup}\n
time_connect:           %{time_connect}\n
time_appconnect:        %{time_appconnect}\n
time_pretransfer:       %{time_pretransfer}\n
time_redirect:          %{time_redirect}\n
time_starttransfer:     %{time_starttransfer}\n
                ----------\n
     time_total:  %{time_total}\n
```

And this is the output for requesting a file that is not on the server:

```
time_namelookup:        0.000
time_connect:           0.198
time_appconnect:        0.000
time_pretransfer:       0.199
time_redirect:          0.000
time_starttransfer:     0.409
                ----------
     time_total:  0.409
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to use -D header.out.
If it is in a script with a loop one can use -D header$counter.out:

```
curl -D header$NUM_TRIES.out -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s  "$IP_PORT/$FILE_NAME"  &
```

and then to count success:

```
more header* | grep 200 -c
```

Failure will be NUM_TRIES - the above value